# Ticking sound when stopping (for example at a traffic light or stop sign) and driving off again

Tags: battery, noise, hyundai, air-filter

I took my Hyundai accent in for a battery change the guy was quite rough when he was putting the battery in, so far so that he was weighing down on the air filter cover and trying to push the air filter back and forth to fit the battery in properly. Ever since then, every time I stop at a traffic light or stop sign, I hear a ticking sound (sound like the ticking sound when the parking prowl is clicking in) and I hear the same sound when I'm taking off again. There appears to be no damage to the air filter cover, but the sound started just after he replaced the battery and pushed the air filter around. Could the air filter be causing this sound? If not, what could it be?

Comment: Without observation I wouldn't venture a legitimate guess. Maybe someone else can. But regardless, the least you should do is check your oil level. The first thing that comes to mind is lifter noise.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! If it's as loud as a parking pawl when it's clicking, that's quite a noise. I cannot readily think of a noise a vehicle would make which may have been upset by the battery installer. Just off the cuff, I'm thinking the two are unrelated (noise onset after battery installation).